# R error: if else statement in a loop, unexpected "}"

Tags: r

I was trying to run these code, and got stuck..

```
a<-data.frame(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14)
n<-1
empty <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=F)
while (n<=5) {
    if (sum((a[,2*n+3]), (a[,2*n+4])) == 13) {
        empty <-data.frame(cbind(empty, 3), n<-n+1
    } else {
        empty <-data.frame(cbind(empty, 2), n<-n+1
    }
}
```

These are what I got:

```
> a<-data.frame(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14)
> n<-1
> empty <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=F)
> while (n<=5) {
+     if (sum((a[,2*n+3]), (a[,2*n+4])) == 13) {
+         empty <-data.frame(cbind(empty, 3), n<-n+1
+     } else {
Error: unexpected '}' in:
"        empty <-data.frame(cbind(empty, 3), n<-n+1
    }"
>         empty <-data.frame(cbind(empty, 2), n<-n+1
+     }
Error: unexpected '}' in:
"        empty <-data.frame(cbind(empty, 2), n<-n+1
    }"
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
```

I've tried many combinations of taking away "{}" or even write the code into the same line with or without these "{}", none of them work. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a syntax error.

Comment: -1 for not searching first. A search for "r unexpected {" on StackOverflow and/or Google yields the answer.

Comment: Moral of the story: use an editor with brace/paren matching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you have unbalanced parenthesis at:

```
empty <-data.frame(cbind(empty, 3), n<-n+1
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
a<-data.frame(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14)
n<-1
empty <- c()
while (n<=5) {
cat("steps",n,"\n")
    if (sum((a[,((2*n)+3)]), (a[,((2*n)+4)])) == 13) {
cat("true in step",n,"\n")
        empty <-cbind(empty, 3)
        } else {
cat("false in step",n,"\n")
        empty <-cbind(empty, 2)                         
    }
    n<-n+1  # this should be after the if condition
}



  steps 1 
false in step 1 
steps 2 
false in step 2 
steps 3 
false in step 3 
steps 4 
false in step 4 
steps 5 
false in step 5 
> empty
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    2    2    2    2    2
```